# What is the most common, unambiguous term for "inheritability"

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance, terminology

What is the most general term that can be used to describe the "inheritability" of a class or class member?

I basically want to know what general way I can ask, "What is this class or class-member's 'inheritability'?", and the answer might  be "abstract", "virtual" or "sealed".

The paradigm I am coming from is primarily for .NET.

### List of Possible Alternatives:

- Inheritability
- Heritability
- Extensibility
- Extendability
- Inheritance Modifier

Comment: Just plain "inheritance", I'd say.  "Modifier" for the kind of inheritance.  Find alternatives at english.se.com

Comment: I would be careful about taking this to EL&U, @Hans. Really technical-jargon related questions tend to get closed quickly--whether merited or not.

Comment: @HansPassant, to be clear, you would say "what is the InheritanceModifier for the member?"

Comment: With a space added, yes.

Comment: Is this question really that bad?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  Don't know if its officially endorsed, but biologists refer to "heritability".

Comment: Yeah, I always found the etymology of INherit perplexing

Comment: This seems to refer to the proportion of variation in a given sample rather than the class of variations.